# can you print/echo message from .Renviron?

Tags: r, rstudio

It is possible to print messages from .Renviron so it is shown in RStudio at startup?

For example:

```
R_LIBS_USER="C:/Rlib/"
APIKEY="blabla"
echo Company envvar set
```

I don't want to use .Rprofile as that is overwriten in projects.

**EDIT:**

This is on locally installed R on windows. We roll out R/Rstudio/Rtools in a software package to all members of a certain AD group. It is in this process that I would like to do some configurations and information.

Comment: What do you intend to do with that?

Comment: We roll out R/Rstudio/Rtools as a software package in my company and we would like to make a few changes to default environment variables, fx pointing to our own package repo. However I would also like to point out to people that we are doing this.

Comment: Are you able to use an `Rprofile.site` file?

Comment: thanks yes! Did not realize that this was present on windows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above you could set environment variables in `R/R-4.x.x/etc/Renviron.site` to set these for all users, even when projects are involved:

```
hello_message = "Hello! This has worked!"
```

Then set `R/R-4.x.x/etc/Rprofile.site` to print these variables:

```
message(Sys.getenv("hello_message"))
```

Then starting a new session, inside outside of a project will set all variables and print all messages:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

...

Hello! This has worked!
>
```

Comment: AH! I had not realised that this was present on windows as well! thanks! That is exactly what I need.